# Using jQuery's prop() to click on a checkbox isn't running the onClick() function set on the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I have two checkboxes that has a onclick() function assigned to them. Now in a button, I have jquery set so that the checkboxes are checked automatically, via prop()

When the button is pressed, the checkboxes are checked but the onclick() function isn't working. How do I make it work? Any idea?

html:

```html
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="mt-5">Tester</h2>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label for="policyinInt">Int</label>
                <input class="form-control" value="0" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="total" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <label for="policyinHex">Hex</label>
                <input class="form-control" value="0" readonly="readonly" type="text" name="totalhex" id="policyinHex" />
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="values" value="256" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" id="bit8" /> <span class="code">0x00000100</span><br>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="values" value="512" type="checkbox" onclick="totalIt()" id="bit9" /> <span class="code">0x00000200</span> <br>
    <button type="button" class="default btn btn-outline-primary">Check the boxes</button>
    <br>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```js
function totalIt() {
    var input = document.getElementsByName("values");
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i].checked) {
        total += parseInt(input[i].value);
      }
    }
    document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = total;
    document.getElementsByName("totalhex")[0].value = decimalToHexString(total);
  }


  function decimalToHexString(number)
  {
    number = number.toString(16).toUpperCase()
    number = "0x"+number;
    return number;
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".default").click(function(){
        $("#bit8").prop("checked", true);
        $("#bit9").prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

jsfiddle of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/fahims/7eyf5v86/

So when the checkboxes are checked manually, the function is working. But when the button is used to trigger the checkbox, the functions arent working. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `totalIt()` after you set the checked properties. Setting properties or values programmatically does not trigger user events

```
$(".default").click(function(){
    $("#bit8, #bit9").prop("checked", true);
    totalIt();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. I looked into jQuery docs to call a function after .prop() but I guess I didn't look for the obvious solution. Cheers!